# Relative positioning on :hover

Tags: css

On hover I use relative positioning with `top` value `-0.3em`. I expect `div` to move up and second `div` move up too. But insted of I have white gap between both `divs`. Why does it happen and how can I solve this?

```css
.one {
    width: 3em;
    line-height: 3em;
    background: yellow;

}

.two {
    width: 3em;
    line-height: 3em;
    background: red;
}

.one:hover {
    line-height: 3.3em;
    position: relative;
    top: -0.3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">one</div>
<div class="two">two</div>
```

Comment: Instead of providing a link to jsfiddle, it is better to use `code snippet` feature of stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a negative margin on `.one` instead:

```css
.one {
    width: 3em;
    line-height: 3em;
    background: yellow;

}

.two {
    width: 3em;
    line-height: 3em;
    background: red;
}

.one:hover {
    margin-top: -0.3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">one</div>
<div class="two">two</div>
```

Since relative positioning does not change the position of an element in the document flow using `top: -0.3em` will not cause `.two` to move up 0.3 em.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div class="zero">
    <div class="one">one</div>
    <div class="two">two</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.one {
    width: 3em;
    line-height: 3em;
    background: yellow;
}
.two {
    width: 3em;
    line-height: 3em;
    background: red;
}
.zero{
    width: 3em;
    line-height: 3em;
}
.zero:hover {
    line-height: 3.3em;
    position: relative;
    top: -0.3em;
}
```